# Unable to start costmaps in navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, 2dcostmap, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I am now working with the Create 2 robot - Roomba 600 platform - with the driver from AutonomyLab and a Hokuyo LRF.
Everything is running perfect, but when I try to enable the navigation stack, the terminal does not log activation of obstacle layer and inflation layer, meaning the costmaps are not enabled on Rviz.

Meanwhile in Gazebo everithing works smoothly with the same parameters settings, so I have two computers connected in the same wireless, this is the procedure I take*

1. launch create and hokuyo driver with `scan:=base_scan` `frame_id:="same name written in urdf file"`
2. `rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan _linearUpdate:=0 _angularUpdate:=0` - starts `LiveSlam()`
3. start `move_base` node with all the parameters of global and local planner, global and local costmap

Communications is realized with a local VPN, port 1194 over UDP.

I tried many possible solutions but no one seems to work in a stable way, so I would like to ask for your help here.
One thing that made me think is about the view_frames output that is very different from gazebo case, which uses `use_sim_time = true`, so a possible cause I was thinking is about time synchronization.

Il'post here some important screenshot and config settings and outputs:

In common_costmap_params.yaml:

```
 #Configuration for the sensors that the costmap will use to update a map
observation_sources: base_scan
base_scan: {sensor_frame: hokuyo_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /base_scan, expected_update_rate: 0.4,observation_persistence: 0.0, marking: true, clearing: true, max_obstacle_height: 0.4, min_obstacle_height: 0.08}
```

From navigation stack logging:

```
[ WARN] [1518088865.446447100]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1518088839.115352594 but the earliest data is at time 1518088855.527055015, when looking up transform from frame [base_footprint] to frame [map]. canTransform returned after 0.100919 timeout was 0.1.
```

From view frames:

```
map->odom->base_footprint->base_link-> to everyone published by robot_state_publisher related to urdf tree
```

It's showing 20 Hz on slam_gmapping, robot driver and LRF sensor with also:

```
Most recent transform: 1518088979.565 ( 26.377 sec old)
Buffer length: 4.900 sec
```

The tf parts published by `robot_state_publisher` are posting: average rate = 10000 Hz

And in these components of the frames at "most recent transform" I have:

```
Most recent transform: 0.000 ( 1518089005.943 sec old)
Buffer length: 0.000 sec
```

The important effect of all of this is that move_base_node ends up to not be a subscriber of /base_scan, so the obstacle plugins cannot enable.

I think wrote the most important effects for me, but if you suggest to post something else i will be happy to.
I would be very grateful to the ones who want to give suggestions or ideas.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282120/unable-to-start-costmaps-in-navigation-stack/) by [nikfio](https://answers.ros.org/users/33613/nikfio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-08**:
Two things to check:

1. make sure all hosts can communicate with each other (`ROS_IP`, `ROS_MASTER_URI`, etc)
2. make sure time is synchronised between the hosts

For more info on both, see [wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-08**:\

> Communications is realized with a local VPN, port 1194 over UDP.

Can you clarify why you decided to do this?

**Comment by [nikfio](https://answers.ros.org/users/33613/nikfio/) on 2018-02-08**:
thank you @gvdhoorn for your reply.
Communication is stable through the tun0 interface, I can ping each other and run teleop_twist without any problem.
About synchronization I didn't take any real precautions yet, I tried today to config ntp but not successfully, do you have any hints?

**Comment by [nikfio](https://answers.ros.org/users/33613/nikfio/) on 2018-02-08**:
Regarding vpn configuration, I tried any solution but that one seemed to be the only one really working.
At first, I preferred TCP but didn7t work out.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-08**:\

> About synchronization I didn't take any real precautions yet, I tried today to config ntp but not successfully, do you have any hints?

the linked wiki article has a section on time synchronisation.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-08**:
I'm not asking about the UDP usage for the VPN, but the use of the VPN in general.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-08**:\

> Communication is stable through the tun0 interface, I can ping each other and run teleop_twist without any problem

I would still recommend to make sure that pub-sub works in both directions (using `rostopic pub ..` and `rostopic echo ..`) as iirc `teleop_twist` is unidirectional.

**Comment by [nikfio](https://answers.ros.org/users/33613/nikfio/) on 2018-02-08**:
Essentially, because by simply setting ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI was not working, I guess it's due to having desktop pc connected to LAN, and laptop to one of the two wireless networks that can change.
Echoing and puclishing are working anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, good. That's out of the way then.

Time synced as well? I find the  `26.377 sec old` a bit much for a TF frame that is published at x Hz per second.

---

Edit:

> SOLVED! it was because of synchronization, my laziness made me avoid section 5 of that article before. The first run of ntpdate was showing an offset of 26 s , after syncing it got to 0.0000008. And now everything is working perfectly, so I can start collect navigation data for my databases. Thanks

Know that runnint `ntpdate` a single time will not keep your system synchronised. Due to having different clocks, they will probably start to diverge more and more over time.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nikfio](https://answers.ros.org/users/33613/nikfio/) on 2018-02-08**:
SOLVED! it was because of synchronization, my laziness made me avoid section 5 of that article before. The first run of ntpdate was showing an offset of 26 s , after syncing it got to 0.0000008.
And now everything is working perfectly, so I can start collect navigation data for my databases.
Thanks

**Comment by [nikfio](https://answers.ros.org/users/33613/nikfio/) on 2018-02-08**:
SOLVED!!
Guys, if you a have a strange result from

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

The first thing to make sure it's to check synchronization and adjust it anyway to be safe.
So, instructions are at the bottom of this page - Section 5 -  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup .